# jquery event fires on item's previous class

Tags: jquery

I use a jquery function on a div.class. In the function I change the class on $(this) so that the function may only be called once per div.  Inspecting the element with Firefox web developer options shows the class as changed, yet the click event for the original class will still fire on the element with the new class.  Code below; I also tried to implement this with toggleClass, exact same results.  Any suggestions?

```
$('div.cluebox').click(function(e) {        
    $( this ).removeClass("cluebox").addClass("emptyBox");;     
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Event handlers aren't bound to classes, they are bound to elements. Even if you change the class, the element still has the same handler bound to it. You can get around this using event delegation with `on()`.

Comment: Thanks, working now with one()

Answer (score 1):

When you bind an event (`click`) to an object, the event stays bound to it until you unbind it. You may be able to simply use the `on` function instead of `click()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want bind event once use jQuery `one()`

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Thanks, working now with one()

Comment: If you're happy with this solution, mark answer as correct;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$('div.cluebox').click(function(e) {        
    $( this ).removeClass("cluebox").addClass("emptyBox");
    $( this).off("click");
});
```

Comment: This have a lot of drawbacks like unbinding all click events. Use `one()` binding or `events namespaces`